# pyc files and security with passwords?

Tags: python, security, pyc

I am in the process of tidying up my code on github by removing .pyc files.

My source code reads a password from a text file outside the git drectory. However can it be extracted from .pyc files? I have no reason to suspect suspicious behaviour but is a good lesson regarding housekeeping.

Comment: If your .py file jsut opens the file and reads it to a variable, then it wont be stored in the .pyc file. The pyc file is just the static bytecode that says "open file x and read in data"

Comment: @TomDalton why not post this as an answer, along with a short demo explaining the bytecode? I would upvote 